# How to get all files in a directory in java applet?

Tags: java, file, maven, resources, japplet

I know how to get all files in a directory in a local app, but when it comes to applet, it doesn't seem to work too well.

The way I normally do:

```
 File file = new File("myDirectory");
 File[] files = file.listFiles();
```

I tried the same thing and it didn't work for my applet. My src has the standard maven project structure. i.e.:

```
src\main\java\mypackage\MyApplet.java
src\main\resources\myDirectory\<... bunch of files here...>
```

So how do I get all the files in myDirectory from MyApplet.java?

Comment: An applet won't have access to the local machine resources unless it is signed and the local machine security policies allow for it to access the resources

Comment: How is the application bundled? Is it generated into a Jar file or is it in a directly on the web server?

Comment: This is a common issue with embedded resources,generally, the API does not provide the means to list these. Generally the best solution is to include a file, possibly generated as part of your build process, that lists all the files you might need to look, then use getClass().getReaource("..."); and read its contents, this way you could then use getResource to get these files...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it is all bundled into one jar

Comment: Yu can't list the resources from within the jar without first being able to access the Jar file directly, since this is an applet, you can't simply find the jar using a File look and use the Zip API to list the zip entries. Instead, generate a file that contains a list of all entries you want find, the use getResource to look this file up and read it

Answer (score 1):

Get directory

```
  File directory = new File(getClass().getResource("/myDirectory").getFile());
```

list files

```
 f.listFiles();
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer TC said about embedded resource. Resource from `myDirectory` will be packed to jar by maven

Comment: Ah. Okay sorry, misread that. But you can't list resources like that if the application is bundled in a Jar. I also doubt that you'd be able to list the files in this manner if he weren't as they would reside on the web server while the applet is executed within the context of the local machine, so the would be part of the web server service and it the local file system...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah all the resources is packaged into one jar, so I'm not sure how to get all the files in the myDirectory.